# Native .NET library for the ASF Format?

Tags: c#, video-streaming, asf

Is there a .NET library for working with ASF files that doesn't use COM/Interop?  I know there is an official spec from Microsoft (http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=31334).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Shameless plug here - I wrote a .NET ASF parser called [AsfMojo](http://asfmojo.codeplex.com/) that's out there on codeplex:

> AsfMojo is an open source .NET ASF
>   parsing library, providing support for
>   parsing Windows Media Audio (WMA) and
>   Windows Media Video (WMV) files.  It
>   offers classes to create streams from
>   packet data within a media file,
>   gather file statistics and extract
>   audio segments or frame accurate still
>   frames. The library parses ASF objects
>   as per the ASF specification revision
>   01.20.05

Check it out and see if it works for you - the ASF parsing itself is pure .NET code (based on the ASF spec), just for creating still frames for particular time offsets Media SDK/InterOp is used under the hood.

Comment: Can it read a non-seekable stream, like a live video stream?  I downloaded the code and tried plugging my URL into the WPF UI sample and it just clocked (my guess is it thought the live stream was a file that eventually would finish downloading...)  If it can read a non-seekable stream, could you post a quick sample/point me in the right direction?

Comment: @Patricker: the WPF sample app is a UI specifically for ASF **files** (similiar to ASF Viewer). If you look at the library code itself you will see that the `AsfFile` class tries to completely parse whatever file you point it to, this includes the time offset of the first and last packet in the file - for streams unfortunately that means that it will stall and/or fail, it's not a supported scenario. You could take that part out, but you will need some code changes in the library itself - what are you trying to do? Maybe there's another way.

Comment: I'm trying to view/process a live video stream from an IP Camera.

Comment: @Patricker: AsfMojo is currently a file / packet oriented library, so unless you chunk up the file you can't use AsfMojo in its current form - that's not to say you couldn't use *parts* of it, i.e. the ASF packet parsing (see `AsfPacket` class) - it all depends on what you want to do with the live stream data.

Comment: I think AsfMojo will be a good place to start, I don't mind getting my hands dirty, I'll start with AsfPacket and see how it goes.

Comment: @Peter: Did you ever get anywhere parsing the live stream from an IP camera? I'm trying to do the same thing.

Comment: @blachniet - I looked into the code to see how feasible it seemed, but quickly decided it was way outside the level of effort I was willing to put into it.  Last time I looked into this I was heading down the path of using either a .NET wrapper for VLC, or Emgu CV.  My goal was cross-platform supporting using Mono, and I believe both of these are doable, and Emgu CV for certain.